# Doing work on demand in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to load a URL when a certain view in my ViewFlipper is shown. How can I determine that X view is being shown, so I can perform the URL downloading logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How can I determine that X view is being shown

Use the [`getDisplayedChild()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getDisplayedChild()) method; it returns an integer which represents the base-zero index of the displayed view. What to do with that index is up to you.